# issues in sub domain setting using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to htaccess. I was tried to set subdomain for following link

`http://www.example.com/shop/shopname/shopid to   http://shopname.example.com/`

i was set wildcard in my DNS Server for my subdomain. And added `serveralias` in `VI Host` like this `*.example.com`

Now how can i redirect using htaccess . please help me i am stuck in this

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/]+) http://$1.example.com/ [L,R]
```

Comment: Let's make sure it works, I will add proper explanation to my answer.

Comment: it's not working . when i redirect the url www.shopname.xxx.com , the landing page go to www.xxx.com

Comment: but in the question you wrote: `http://www.xxx.com/shop/shopname/shopid to http://shopname.xxx.com/` and now you're using `www.shopname.xxx.com`.

Comment: sorry not only www.shopname.xxx.com and also http://shopname.xxx.com/ this url was not working. and i have doubt . how can i pass my shopid to getting details page

Comment: I am on mobile now so will attend after going back to my computer. Can you meanwhile clarify your requirements clearly like which URL you want to redirect and what conditions.

Comment: my original URL is http://www.xxx.com/shop/shopname/shopid , and i just want to create my each shop-name as a sub-domain. like following link http://shopname.xxx.com/ . this is i want

Comment: But have you created DNS entries for `shopname1.xxx.com` and `shopname2.xxx.com` etc and their `VirtualHost` entries as well?

Comment: can you give some example for that

Comment: Example of what? Question is about rewrite rule not about server administration and DNS registration. Contact your server admin.

Comment: If it worked out can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.